# Question on referencing global properties

Tags: javascript

To reference a property of a global object, we can use `clearInterval` instead of `global.clearInterval`. `console.log` instead of `window.console.log`. Can I confirm that this not having to type 'object.property' is a unique quality of the global object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. Global variables are automatically made properties of the global object, which is named `global` in node.js, `window` in browsers.

Note that if you have a local variable with the same name as a global variable, you'll need to use the `object.property` syntax to access the global variable, since using the name without an object prefix will access the local variable. E.g.

```
function foo () {
    let clearInterval = 0;
    window.clearInterval(someVariable);
}
```